Install PHP 7.4 and set PATH or php.executablePath on WSL
I am working with VSCode, and while the XAMPP installation is on Windows, the projects are managed from Ubuntu through WSL. I have already set the environment variables, but it's still not functioning correctly.
I came across an answer suggesting the addition of two lines in the settings.json file. I tried this, but it didn't resolve the issue. I'm hoping you can provide some guidance on what to do next.

finally add the lines in settings.json but using the WSL path instead of the windows one
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/mnt/c/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "/mnt/c/xampp/php/php.exe"
}

